# angular: http post not sending data to php file

Tags: php, angularjs

I am facing strange issue with angular ajax request.
Basically i am sending two data  to php file by angular http request.
Here is the code.

```
var allData={'city_id': city, 'uid': uid}

 $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'update_exec.php',
      data : allData,
     // headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }  // set the headers  
     headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
  })
```

And here is the php file.

```
  $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $city = $_POST['city_id'];
echo $uid;
echo $city;

var_dump($_POST);
```

Output is blank for var_dump.

when i check in the firebug i am getting below details in XHR.
**Status -200
Method - Options
But no data in param.**

If i change headers to `{ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }` this.

Then i am getting **Status - 200 and Method - POST also i can see data in param.**

But for both cases data us not coming in php file.

Comment: do angular & api are on same domain or different?

Comment: they are on same domain. for get request it is working fine.

Comment: can you try printing `var_dump( file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: no output for var_dump( file_get_contents('php://input'));.

Comment: `NULL` is being displayed on `var_dump` ?

Comment: if i use      headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } then i can see the value for var_dump( file_get_contents('php://input')); why is that?

Comment: I have added an answer. Please check that if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to send the object, you don't need to add manually any headers. Try this

```
 var allData={'city_id': city, 'uid': uid}

 $http({
      method  : 'POST',
      url     : 'update_exec.php',
      data : allData
  }).then(function mySucces(response) {
        //SUCCESS CALLBACK
    }, function myError(response) {
        //ERROR CALLBACK
    });
```

In PHP, You can get the data via `$_POST` or `file_get_contents('php://input')` First one provides you the POST data; latter one provides the raw input. If you need to use the json headers, then you need to convert the allData to JSON String via `JSON.stringify(allData)` & then send it.